# Google Analytics in Meteor with Iron Router

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, coffeescript, meteor, iron-router

Here is my attempt to get Google Analytics working with Iron Router

In `lib/analytics.js` I have the following code (pasted from the code page in analytics):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-45905917-2', 'ec2-54-246-15-224.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com');
}
```

Then, in `client/router.coffee` is the following code:

```
Router.configure layoutTemplate: 'layout'

Router.map ->
    @route 'home', 
        path: '/'
        template: 'home'
        after: -> ga('send', 'pageview')

    for link in Pages.links
        route =  
            path: link.url
            template: link.toTemplate 
            after: -> ga('send', 'pageview')
        @route link.toTemplate, route
```

But this did not seem to have worked. How do I solve this?

EDIT TO ADD:

I have tried GAnalytics, but I had a lot of issues with my deployment setup and Meteor settings

Comment: Hi there, this is a workaround so I will not post this as an answer, but I recently got it working by pasting Google Analyics code within `<script></script>` tags within my `html` template. Like so: view-source:http://mixtape.meteor.com/

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.bicobic.com/posts/BkFDo4CqcSnGcGtri This loads GA-Script via a scriptloader which is not necessary but it shows the way to include the script in a template. Call it in your layout. Check the Google Analytics Debugger for Chrome too.

Answer (score 1):

Execute those codes when the templates are rendered, take a look at [template_rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered)

Answer (score 1):

The way we solve for this is calling the page function onAfterAction

```
Router.onAfterAction(function() {
  analytics.page(this.route.getName());
});
```

A helpful hint, when using the Analytics.js project, is if you call `analytics.debug()` in your console you'll be able to see what your code is doing.

We've used Analytics.js on a few meteor projects already so we extracted it into a meteor package:

[okgrow:analytics](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/analytics)

We use Iron Router on most projects, so if it's installed, this package will automatically send page views based on route names (but doesn't complain if the project doesn't use Iron Router). 
It also automatically logs user login/logout if you have the Accounts package installed and, of course, you can setup `track()` calls on events.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The option, in my opinion, is to use Template.rendered. One issue that you might face is that you need to be aware of Template data changes. Example:

```
Template.yourTemplate.rendered = function(){
  var self = this; //In case you need it but self.data IS NOT REACTIVE

  this.autorun(function(){
    //This is reactive
    var data = Template.currentData();

    //place your analitycs code here

  });
}
```

I recommend using it on template containers.

Comment: but then I'd have to add it to each template I use.. would be better to write once use everywhere. Wait.. template containers? Sounds like a hack.

Comment: also, why does the analytics code need to be in autorun?

Comment: It's not an hack, it's actually necessary. Imagine a left side panel where pick a magazine article and container in the center. When you choose a magazine article on the left you can use the Router or simply use the Session or any Reactive Dict. Using Session/Reactive Dict is faster but you need to keep track of chances. Since Meteor is for SPA, I would choose Reactive Dict over Routing, but it really depends on your project specs.

Comment: Almost forgot: even using routing (Iron Router), when you change the Route, the page isn't going to loaded again!! So the Route changes, things get recomputed but the template isn't rendered again. Blaze keeps track of dependencies and only updates the necessary DOM parts. You can check EventMind videos, they explain it in detail: https://www.eventedmind.com/